# Google sheet error: "Invalid argument: parent.mimeTypeDetails "

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting error: Invalid argument: parent.mimeTypeDetails

Trying to run simple script:

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("destfolderid"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById("destfolderid").makeCopy("particularfilename", destFolder); 
}
```

Comment: Is this just a typo? `DriveApp.getFileById("destfolderid")` you should provide a file id instead of a folder id. I wasn't able to replicate your issue, the mentioned error did not occur. Can you provide a screenshot of the execution log to verify the problematic line of code and the complete code if the provided code is just a partial code?

Comment: The error message in the title of the question does not appear to be related, in any way that I can see, to the code in the body of the question.

Comment: I tried to put ID of file and also ID of folder. When I input id of file mentioned arror appered. When I input ID of folder some error other with Acces Denied. Here is file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SBoJzpLjA0h77hPGlLi44_h9rMbTC4XSFDYH03tJUYk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It works fine this way:

```
const folderID = '###';  <---- ID of your folder
const fileID   = '@@@';  <---- ID of your file

function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).makeCopy("particularfilename", destFolder); 
}
```

And of course you need full access to the folder if you want to add a file inside of it.